# XamSchedule (WPF): show more weeks with scrollbar

Tags: wpf, infragistics, schedule

I use the control XamSchedule (WPF) from Infragistics. I need it to show all the appointments from the user. But I cant show more then one week. I want to scroll to the next week. 
I can change between Week and WorkWeek. This is ok because I want to hide the weekend sometimes.

[image: Week View]

Is this possible that I can scroll to the next week?